# Deploy multiple django instances on one Host

Tags: ubuntu, django, lighttpd

I am trying to setup multiple *Django* instances on one Host with *lighttpd*. My problem is to get Djangos *FCGI* working on subdirectories served by my Webserver.

So my aim is the following:

- www.myhost.org/django0 -> django1.fcgi on localhost:3000
- www.myhost.org/django1 -> django2.fcgi on localhost:3001
- www.myhost.org/django2 -> django3.fcgi on localhost:3002

Unfortunately the following configuration doesn't even work for one:

```
$HTTP["url"] =~ "^/django0/static($|/)" {
        server.document-root = "/home/django0/django/static/"
}

$HTTP["url"] =~ "^/django0/media($|/)" {
        server.document-root = "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/admin/media/"
}

$HTTP["url"] =~ "^/django0($|/)" {
        proxy.server = ( "" => ( (
                "host" => "127.0.0.1",
                "port" => "3001",
                "check-local" => "disable",
                ) )
        )
}
```

The only response I get is an **404** and even this takes a long time till I get this. I found nothing suspicious neither in the *access.log* nor in the *error.log*.

Comment: You can run multiple [sites](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/sites/?from=olddocs) on one Django instance.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, but I have good reasons not to do this, because some apps are unstable.